# Star vs. plus quantifier in the variable-width negative lookbehind

Tags: c#, regex, regex-lookarounds

Silly question here... I'm trying to match white-space inside the line while **ignoring the leading spaces/tabs** and came up with these regex strings, but I can't figure out why only one is working (C# regex engine):

```
(?<!^[ \t]*)[ \t]+       // regex 1. (with *)
(?<!^[ \t]+)[ \t]+       // regex 2. (with +)
```

Note the **star** vs. **plus** repetitions in the *negative look-ahead*. When matching these against `"  word1 word2"` (2 leading spaces):

```
⎵⎵word1⎵word2             
      ^                  // 1 match for regex 1. (*)

⎵⎵word1⎵word2             
^^     ^                 // 2 matches for regex 2. (+)
 ^     ^                 // why not match like this?
```

Why does only version 1. (star) work here and version 2. (plus) not match the second leading space?

I presume that it's because of the higher priority of the greedy `+` from `[ \t]+` over the look-ahead's, but how can I rationalize to expect this?

Comment: This is actuall very easy to understand. The negative lookbehind just checks if the current position is not preceded with the lookbehind pattern. So, the `+` version will match the initial whitespace because the start of string is not preceded with a start of string and at least 1 whitespace.

Comment: So basically the engine: 1. takes the 1st character (1st space) with repetition of length 1; 2. applies repetition again, so 1st 2 spaces match; 3. applies repetition again but 3rd char is not a space, so rolls back; 4. goes on to check the negative look-behind, which matches (no spaces btw current char and start of line; 5. matching is success. Perhaps step 4. goes to the beginning...

Comment: You totally miss the fact that it is not the `[ \t]+` that is checked first, but the lookbehind. The pattern is parsed from left to right, not vice versa. Step 1: the lookbehind check,  and if the result of the check is true, Step 2 occurs, matching the horizontal whitespaces. Once the match is found, the next match is searched for from the end of the preceding match.

Comment: All right, so it's the last thing I mentioned. Thanks :)

Comment: Yes, that is right, the lookbehind check is the first here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In short**:

The negative lookbehind just checks if the *current position* is not preceded with the lookbehind pattern and the result of the check is either *true* (yes, go on matching) or *false* (stop processing the pattern, go for the next match). The check is not affecting the regex index, the engine remains at one and the same location after performing the check.

In the current expressions, the lookbehind pattern is checked *first* (as the pattern is parsed from *left to right*, not vice versa), and only if the lookbehind check returns true the `[ \t]+` pattern is tried. In the first expression, the *negative* lookbehind returns *false* as the lookbehind pattern finds a match (the start of string). The second expression *negative* lookbehind returns *true* because there is no start of string followed with 1 or more spaces/tabs at the beginning of a string.

**Here is the logic behind the 2 expressions:**

- The lookbehind check is performed first. In the first expression, `(?<!^[ \t]*)` is trying to match at the beginning of a string. A beginning of a string has no beginning of a string (`^`) followed with 0+ spaces or tabs. It is important to note that a lookbehind implementation in .NET checks the string in the opposite direction, flips the string, and searches for zero or more tabs and the string boundary. In case of `(?<!^[ \t]*)`, the lookbehind returns false because there is a start position before 0 spaces or tabs (note we are still at the beginning of a string). The second expression lookbehind, `(?<!^[ \t]+)`, returns true, because there is no tab or space before the start of string at the 0th index in the string, and thus, the `[ \t]+` consuming pattern grabs the leading horizontal whitespace. That moves the regex index further and another match is found later in the string.
- After failure at the beginning of the string, the first expression tries to match after the first space. However, the `(?<!^[ \t]*)` returns false because there is beginning of string followed with 1 space (the first one). Same story repeats with the position after the second space. The only spaces matched with the first `(?<!^[ \t]*)[ \t]+` expression are those that are not at the beginning of the string.

**Lookahead analogy**

Check the analogous lookahead patterns: a [`[ \t]+(?![ \t]+$)`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5b+%5ct%5d%2b%28%3f!%5b+%5ct%5d%2b%24%29&i=bb+bb++) pattern will find both whitespace chunks in `"bb bb  "`, while [`[ \t]+(?![ \t]*$)`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5b+%5ct%5d%2b%28%3f!%5b+%5ct%5d*%24%29&i=bb+bb++) will not match those at the end of the string. The same logic applies: 1) the `*` version allows matching an empty string, so the end of string is found and the negative lookahead returns false, the match is failed. When the `+` version encounters and consumes the trailing whitespaces, the regex engine, staying at the end of string, cannot find 1 or more spaces/tabs followed with another end of string, thus, the negative lookahead returns true and the trailing whitespaces are matched.